# scipy.sparse.csr_matrix matrix-matrix multiplication implementation

Tags: scipy, matrix-multiplication, csr

I'm wondering how does scipy implement the matrix-matrix multiplication in the csr sparse format. Does anyone have a pseudo-code of that? A python implementation would be even better. To be more clear, suppose we have matrix A and B in csr format, such that they both have .data, .indices and .indptr attributes. C = A*B.  How to compute those three attributes of C?Sorry for my bad english and I hope I'm clear.

Thanks,

yang

Comment: It is C++, but the source code of that functionality is [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L476). I think it is easy to follow and richly commented, but feel free to ask follow up questions if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks a lot. Their comments are indeed pretty good, but C++ code is still quite obscur for me though :(